# ¿Como comparar dos colas (QUEUE) e ir añadiendo el valor mas pequeño en una lista (LIST? JAVA

Tags: java

```
 List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<>(
            Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2, 5, 10, 9, 20, 25, 80, 120}));
 List<Integer> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    l2.add(1);
    l2.add(6);
    l2.add(4);
    l2.add(2);
    l2.add(20);
    l2.add(9);
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(); //lista donde quiero añadir las 2 colas ordenadas.
Collections.sort(l1);//ordeno las listas
Collections.sort(l2);//ordeno las listas
//creo las colas añadiendo las listas con los valores ordenados
Queue<Integer> q1 = new LinkedList<>(l1);
Queue<Integer> q2 = new LinkedList<>(l2);
```

Comment: ¿Que haz intentado hacer, donde tienes dificultad?

Comment: Pues lo que quiero hacer es comparar dos colas creadas a raiz de dos listas e ir comparando el valor mas pequeño entre ellas e ir añadiendo estos valores en una nueva lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar 2 metodos de `Queue`:

- `peek()`: mira el siguiente elemento, pero no lo remueve.
- `poll()`: remueve el siguiente elemento y lo retorna.

Con estos 2 puedes comprar el siguiente elemento y agregar el menor, luego tendrías que agregar los que sobran.

```
while(!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()) {
    if(q1.peek().compareTo(q2.peek()) <= 0) {
        result.add(q1.poll());
    } else {
        result.add(q2.poll());
    }
}
while(!q1.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(q1.poll());
}
while(!q2.isEmpty()) {
    result.add(q2.poll());
}
```

Comment: Ostia funciona perfectamente. Muchisimas gracias tio !!

Comment: @Cristian recuerda entonces aceptar la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este algoritmo funcional simple para guiarte

```
public void comparar(List<Integer> digitos1, List<Integer> digitos2 ){
    List<Integer> nuevo = new ArrayList<>();

    IntStream.range(0, digitos1.size()).forEach( i ->{

        System.out.println("d1: "+digitos1.get(i)+" - d2: "+digitos2.get(i));
        System.out.println("comparacion: "+(digitos1.get(i).compareTo(digitos2.get(i))) +" \n");

        switch(digitos1.get(i).compareTo(digitos2.get(i))){
            case -1: 
                System.out.println("add -1");
                nuevo.add(digitos1.get(i));
                break;
            case 0:
                System.out.println("add 0");
                nuevo.add(digitos1.get(i));
                break;
            case 1:
                System.out.println("add 1");
                nuevo.add(digitos2.get(i));
                break;

        }

    });

      nuevo.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar a ver que tal. Pero muchas gracias de antenamano.

Comment: En muchos sentidos esta respuesta no es correcta, las entradas deberian ser Queue, no necesariamente del mismo tamaño e Integer.compareTo no define -1 y 1 como retorno.

Comment: Si, eso he visto, que no es del todo correcta porque si una lista es mas grande que otra ya no funciona.